# convert a string into a javascript array with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long string containing text information about a multi-page image file.
Here is an example:

```
test.tif[0] TIFF 1962x2668+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u test.tif[1] TIFF 
1952x2688+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u test.tif[2] TIFF 1650x2200+0+0 
DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01 etc..
```

I need to convert the string into an array of image informations like this:

```
[
    'test.tif[0] TIFF 1962x2668+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u',
    'test.tif[1] TIFF 1952x2688+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u',
    'test.tif[2] TIFF 1650x2200+0+0 DirectClass 1-bit 12.8M 0.000u 0:01',
    etc..
]
```

Probably with some sort of regular expression it is possible to separate the part of the string starting with `[x]`, including the name of the left side that can change every time. 
Or maybe there is a better way to do that ?

Comment: So you want to match from `something.tif[somenumber]` up to the next occurrence?

Comment: @MattBurland yes something.tif[somenumber], or even better something.someImageExtension[somenumber] –  Cris69 11 mins ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var array = string.split(/ (?=test\.tif\[\d+\])/);
```

This uses a lookahead to split on each space that is followed by `test.tif[<number>]`.

To handle different extensions, you could change the `tif` portion of the regex to `[a-zA-Z]+` to allow anything or something like `(?:tif|gif|png)` to allow only specific extensions.